# Can't read n bytes of data at an assembly label via GDB

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, x86-64

I'm not sure if I'm misreading the GDB documentation about the `x` and `print` commands, but it seems to suggest that its use as `x {expr}` should treat `expr` as an address. I have a labeled bit of data in my program's `.data` section, called `string`:

```
SECTION .data
string: db "KANGAROO"
```

If I want to inspect the memory at address `string` with x, this happens:
`(gdb) x/8 string`
yields:
`'string' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type`

Why is GDB complaining about type casting? All I've asked it to do is go to memory location `string` (which is clearly an address - if I load `string` into a register it looks distinctly like an offset).

simply casting, assuming that it wants me to cast `string` as a pointer to some data:

`(gdb) x/8 (char*)string`

does something really bizarre: it somehow knows to read the exact number of bytes of `string` (I tried this with a few different sizes of string), shows those bytes, but then complains that it tried to access memory at the address of the *value* at `string`, rather than `string` itself:

`0x4f4f5241474e414b: Cannot access memory at address 0x4f4f5241474e414b`

where the data `0x4f4...` are the ASCII codes of the string. So it's jumped completely over the address of `string` and is now treating the data contained at the location `string` as an address expression. What?

Where am I getting confused here? Is the `string` label not actually a memory address? Because I would have expected the `x` command to simply treat it as an address expression, but it doesn't seem to. And why is it asking me to cast data? I just want to read n bytes at a particular labeled location in `.data`. What am I missing here?

Comment: You should not use `x` without a type. Do `x/8c` and then it should work.

Comment: `x/s` results in the same message about needing to cast `string`. supplying any parameters (inc. length) doesn't seem to convince it to display anything. still unclear why it's having trouble with this. FWIW, the documentation suggests that typing is optional (it accepts only an address, an address with formatting, or an address with formatting and length), but again, maybe I'm misreading it.

Comment: *should treat `expr` as an address.* Yes, but there's no implicit `&` address-of operator. If you have a `char *ptr` variable in C, `x ptr` uses the *value* of the variable and examines the pointed-to memory.  Not the 8 bytes of pointer data itself like you'd get from `x &ptr` to examine memory at the address of that C variable or asm symbol.  The type isn't the problem, it defaults to 32-bit chunks dumped as hex.  It's the same problem you'd have if you used `p` *without* a cast.

Comment: Hmm, looks like gdb handles symbols differently depending on section. Indeed, given your example in `.data` I get the same error and have to use `&string` (which is confusing since gdb source language is set to asm not C).

Comment: I'm able to get it by indirection using `info address string` and then `x/8 {address shown}` without any typing information. so I'm still completely at sea about what `string` even is within GDB, what information it contains outside of the assembly, and what GDB is doing with the address expressions.

Answer (score 1):

All GDB has for `string` is a symbol *value*. GDB has no idea how to turn that symbol value into an address of something.

Consider the following program:

```
const char *string1 = "abcd";
const char string2[] = "efgh";

int main() { return 0; }
```

When compiled without `-g`, you need to tell GDB that `&string2` is the address of a string in memory, but `&string1` is the address of a pointer to a string:

```
(gdb) x/s *(char**)&string1
0x2004: "abcd"

(gdb) x/s (char*)&string2
0x2009 <string2>:       "efgh"
```

Comment: GDB certainly seems to know that `string` is either an address or that it represents data at a particular address, since casting it reads from the address it represents, just in a very strange way. This is all a bit over my head - I am compiling with -g, but it's not clear to me what `string` is within GDB (is it a pointer? an empty symbol? literally the data at the address?), but I'm able to inspect things by using `info address string` and then inspecting by `x/n {address}` without any typing information, which is what I expected to able to do in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `x /8c &string`** to dump memory at the address labeled with that symbol.

---

> it seems to suggest that its use as `x {expr}` should treat `expr` as an address

GDB syntax is a lot like C.  If it doesn't know the type from debug info, it assumes it's a value type like C `int string` or `float string` where the bare name evaluates to the value stored in memory, not like `char string[]` where using the bare name in most contexts gives you the address.

When GDB doesn't have a type, it refuses to evaluate expressions that use the symbol without an `&` address-of operator.  That includes the expression you use as an operand for the `x` command.  It doesn't implicitly take the address of a symbol.

GDB knows that `string` is a symbol in the symbol-table of your executable, and therefore it *has* an address, but that's all GDB knows.  It doesn't know that `string` should evaluate to the symbol's address, whether it's an operand for `x` or `print`.  (Although `print` does have a lot of magic built-in for when GDB does know the type.)

For example:

```
char *ptr = "aaaaaaa";
int main(){
// set a breakpoint here and  x ptr
}
```

```
$ gcc -g ptr.c            # build *with* debug info
$ gdb ./a.out
...
(gdb) x ptr
0x555555556004: 0x61616161       # the ASCII bytes in .rodata
(gdb) x &ptr
0x555555558010 <ptr>:   0x55556004   # the low 4 bytes of the 8-byte pointer in .data
```

If you have a `char *ptr` variable in C, `x ptr` uses the value of the variable and examines the pointed-to memory, dumping .  Not the 8 bytes of pointer data itself like you'd get from `x &ptr` to examine memory at the address of that C variable or asm symbol.

The type isn't the problem, it defaults to 32-bit chunks dumped as hex. It's the same problem you'd have if you used p without a cast.